# Check hard disk type on SQL server using scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any script to find out the type of  hard disk being used on SQL Server?

Comment: Does this help? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/05/sql-server-get-a-list-of-fixed-hard-drive-and-free-space-on-server/

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I am looking for the hard disk specifications that are currently on my SQL Server. I am not looking for how much available disk space I have. I only have Management Studio that can remotely connect to SQL Server. I don't have direct access to the operation system.